# Average day gap in between a repeat order for each product

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions, repeat, purchase-order

Can someone please help me to find the average time between first and second purchase on a product level.

This is what I have written -

```sql
Select A.CustomerId,A.ProductId , A.OrderSequence, (Case WHEN OrderSequence = 1 THEN OrderDate END) AS First_Order_Date,
MAX(Case WHEN OrderSequence = 2 THEN OrderDate END) AS Second_Order_Date
From
(
Select t.CustomerId, t.ProductId, t.OrderDate,
Dense_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.CustomerId, t.ProductId ORDER BY OrderDate Asc) as OrderSequence  
From Transactions t (NOLOCK)
Where t.SiteKey = 01
Group by t.CustomerId, t.ProductId, t.OrderDate)
A
Where A.OrderSequence IN (1,2)
Group By A.Customer_Id, A.ProductId, A.OrderSequence, A.OrderDate
```

Sample Data:

[image]

Comment: Do you *really* need that `NOLOCK` table hint?

Comment: difficult without any sample data and table structures unfortunately

Comment: You should add table schema and sample data script (or sqlfiddle link) and using your query where is the challenge? and what output using your query and what is the required output.

Comment: Hey I have attached a picture for reference, my apologies I'm still a newbie here. I'm expecting to find out the first order date and second order date for a product id ordered by a customer in the same row

Comment: Don't add data as images. Add sample data *and expected output* as text, preferably as `CREATE TABLE` `INSERT` statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like row-numbering and `LEAD` should do the trick for you here.

- Don't use `NOLOCK` unless you *really* know what you're doing
- It's unclear if you want the results to be partitioned by `CustomerId` also. If not, you can remove it everywhere in the query

```sql
SELECT
  A.CustomerId,
  A.ProductId,
  AVG(DATEDIFF(day, OrderDate, NextOrderDate))
FROM
(
    SELECT
      t.CustomerId,
      t.ProductId,
      t.OrderDate,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.CustomerId, t.ProductId ORDER BY OrderDate) AS rn,
      LEAD(OrderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY t.CustomerId, t.ProductId ORDER BY OrderDate) AS NextOrderDate
    FROM Transactions t
    WHERE t.SiteKey = '01'
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
GROUP BY
  t.Customer_Id,
  t.ProductId;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding Charlie! :) Appreciate it.